# Ruby idiom to initialize class not object

Tags: ruby

What's the standard way to initialize class (not object)?

What I did is created `class_initialize` method and call it.
But I am ex C# programmer. Is there a better way?

```
class Specs
  class << self
    def universal_properties
      [:hp, :engine_volume]
    end
    def compound_universal_properties
      [:hp_per_volume]
    end
    def convertible_properties
      [:weight, :torque]
    end
    def compound_convertible_properties
      [:weight_per_hp]
    end

    private
    def define_methods(type)
      define_method(type) { instance_variable_get("@#{type}") }
      define_method("#{type}=") do |value_and_unit|
        send(type).send(:set, value_and_unit)
      end
    end

    def class_initialize
      universal_properties.each { |p| define_methods(p) }
      convertible_properties.each { |p| define_methods(p) }
      compound_universal_properties.each { |p| define_methods(p) }
      compound_convertible_properties.each { |p| define_methods(p) }
    end
  end
  class_initialize

  public

  def initialize
    @weight = ConvertibleProperty.new(:weight)
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

**Less important details:**
I see by first answer that this code is confusing people and this is too long for a comment.

I didn't just create attr_accessors because for example `:weight` and `:torque` are class `ConvertibleProperty` and have functionality like `imperial.value`, `imperial.unit`, `metric.value`, `metric.unit`, `empty?`...

I am calling this code like this:

```
specs = Specs.new
specs.weight = 800, 'kg'
specs.hp     = 300
specs.torque = 210, :metric
```

When I type `specs.weight = 10, 'kg'` ruby translates that to `specs.weight=([10, 'kg'])` and I don't want to replace weight with array `[10, 'kg']`, I want to call `set` method on it which stores original unit and value and provides `metric` and `imperial` function which each retuns a struct containing `value` and `unit`.

Comment: Could you include an example of how you want to call this code? For e.g. `Specs.weight('etc')`, or `Specs.new('etc')`

Comment: Done. I hope it explains it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the most idiomatic way would be to DSL this:

```
class Specs
  def initialize
    instance_exec(&Proc.new) if block_given?
  end
  def weight!(*args)
    weight = ...
  end
  ...
end

specs = Specs.new do 
  weight! 800, 'kg'
  hp! 300
  torque! 210, :metric
end
```

Other way round would be to specify proper accessors:

```
def torque=(*args)
  # 210, :metric
  @torque = ConvertibleProperty.new(...)
end
```

---

If the amount of variables is high, one might want to automize the creation of accessors:

```
PROPERTIES = {
  'UniversalProperty': [:hp, :engine_volume],
  'CompoundUniversalProperty': [:hp_per_volume],
  'ConvertibleProperty': [:weight, :torque],
  'CompoundConvertibleProperty': [:weight_per_hp]
}.freeze

PROPERTIES.each do |type, *props|
  props.each do |prop|
    attr_reader prop
    define_method "#{prop}=" do |*args|
      self.instance_variable_set(:"@#{prop}", Kernel.const_get(type).new(*args))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. If I was doing it again, I'd do it like second case cause I like the `specs.weight = 10, 'lbs'` syntax. But I have 13 properties which are 4 different types (classes). This seems like a mess to create accessors for all manually.

Comment: What about my `class_initialize` idea, is that non ruby way for some reason and why?

Comment: Whether you want to meta-program those 13 props, you might do it in more explicit manner, please see an update.

Comment: Thank you. So you'd just put code like that in the class, you wouldn't wrap it into a method and then call that method like I did with `class_initialize` ?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to have the method unless you are going to call this method at leasr twice. It just makes code noisy.

Comment: Thank you that was my original question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically, you would not create assignment methods to respond in such a way, and there isn't much value to metaprogramming here yet. I would work to write it out in simple terms first, then possibly refactor later if it becomes cumbersome to manage your different types.

Here is the idiomatic way:

```
class Specs
  def weight
    @weight ||= ConvertibleProperty.new(:weight)
  end

  def torque
    @torque ||= ConvertibleProperty.new(:torque)
  end

  # [..]
end
```

#### usage

```
specs = Specs.new
specs.weight.set(800, 'kg')
specs.torque.set(210, :metric)
```

Comment: Thanks. That is how I started, except I initialized `@weight`, `@torque`... in `#initialize`. But why no suggestions for class_initialize. Is that like a big no-no in ruby to initalize the class? Why?